# running python executable in linux

Tags: python, ubuntu

I've found a few other people asking this question, but the answers for their problem are not helping me. I trying to learn python and trying to make a file executable.

The practice script runs when I type `python ./userPrompt.py`.
But when I try to run it as an executable (just `./userPrompt.py`).

I've successful change it `chmod +x`
And here's what i have in the top line of the file:

```
    #! /user/bin/env python
```

and here's the error I get

```
   bash: ./userPrompt.py: /user/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

But the thing is if I go to `/user/bin` I can find `env`. So it definitely exists. Why can't Ubuntu find it??

I appreciate any help people can give me on this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The path is `/usr`, not `/user`.

Comment: `/usr` may confuse, but `umount` is worse!

Comment: wow ... i feel like an idiot -- i feel like I should lose rep points for foolishness. Everything works now, thanks.

Comment: @Jeff don't feel too bad, we've all been there (the difference being some of us won't admit it :-)

Comment: Jeff - hey, accept my answer, and I'll never tell a soul.  @Levon - speak for yourself.  I was born knowing my way around Unix, despite the fact that it hadn't been invented yet. ;-)