# How to execute python script in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, python-3.x, gnome-terminal

I would like to make a python script that would do some work with interfaces file in Linux.

How I may make this script executable in Linux? I would to open it with `sudo` and it would do some commands in terminal.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068477/running-python-executable-in-linux ? all the answers are already there.

Comment: Some people have come to think that `sudo` is normal, but don't use `sudo` unless you know that your commands actually need root permissions.

Comment: It does ! I want to compleatly remove the interfaces file and replace it with new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make callable

```
chmod u+x <filename here>
```

first line in file with shebang to determine how the script should be executed:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

execute with

```
./<filename here>
```